# Custom subView (like AlertView) Navigation Flow (Delegate)

Tags: objective-c

I have a MainViewController that add a CustomModalViewController, as a subview.

When the delegate function `customModalClickedButtonAtIndex` is called, the `MainViewController` navigation is supposed to push the `NextView`.

The CustomModal is being `removeFromSuperview` correctly, but theres a problem because the `NextView` is not being pushed.

---

MainViewController.m

```
...
@implementation MainViewController

- (IBAction)btnShowCustomModal:(id)sender
{
    // Add the CustomModal as a SubView
    CustomModalViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CustomModal"];
        viewController.delegate = self;
        [self.navigationController addChildViewController:viewController];
        [viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
        [self.navigationController.view addSubview:viewController.view];
}

#pragma mark - CustomModalViewControllerDelegate
- (void)customModalClickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        // Left Button
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        // Right Button
    }

    // Try to push the NextView. It's not working properly.
    UIViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NextView"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
...
@end
```

---

---

CustomModalViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol CustomModalViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)customModalClickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;

@end


@interface CustomModalViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <CustomModalViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

CustomModalViewController.m

```
#import "CustomModalViewController.h"

@interface CustomModalViewController ()

@end

@implementation CustomModalViewController

- (IBAction)btnLeft:(id)sender
{
    // Close the Modal and return the delegate method.
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];

    [self.delegate customModalClickedButtonAtIndex:0];
}

- (IBAction)btnRight:(id)sender
{
    // Close the Modal and return the delegate method.
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];

    [self.delegate customModalClickedButtonAtIndex:1];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

RemoveFromSuperview will clean up the view and you aren't guaranteed execution afterwards. So the code never gets called.

You will want to do one of two things.
1. Have the calling view handle closing it, and since it is the one adding it, it wouldn't be bad to do so.
2. Call your code first, and juggle the order to make sure it all still works.